# Powershell writes out Count when trying to only compare

Tags: powershell

I wrote a short powershell script to monitor some processes that must complete before a program can be started. I created an array to list the processes to check, and another one that is dynamically fille (to avoid some other problems) with processes that have shut down. I have two popups, both of which will eventually time out. I am figuring that part out. My problem is, the compile script specifies noConsole. But when I run the executable (our compiler is proprietary, no sharing), I get extra popup windows stating the size of my dynamically created array. I don't want this. Can someone tell me how to NOT get the count to pop up? And having popups instead of a console is required, so I cannot change that. Thanks for any help

```
#verify that all processes have ended
function verifyProcessEnd{
    DO{   
        foreach($name in $processList){
            if((Get-Process $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null){
            #fill our finished processes list
                if($finishedList -notcontains($name)){
                    $finishedList.Add($name) 
                }
            }
        }
    }while($finishedList.Count -ne $processList.Count)
}

#____________________________________ Main ____________________________________#
#get the list of processes to check for - these must match the service name (minus extension) in task manager
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$processList =  'WINWORD', 'msedge' #can be changed to any processes
# create a new list for finished processes. 
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$finishedList = @()
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("Please wait for all processes to end before starting the program", 10, "Done",0x1)
verifyProcessEnd
$wshell.Popup("All startup processes have completed. It is safe to start the program", 10, "Done",0x1)
```

Comment: `[void]$finishedList.Add($name)` or `$null = $finishedList.Add($name)` or `$finishedList.Add($name) | Out-Null`

Comment: All of the above work. Thanks! I'm going with the out-null option, I like it best.